# Which Java library lets me initialize an object's properties from a properties file?

Tags: java

Is there a Java library that lets you "deserialize" a properties file directly into an object instance?

**Example:** say you have a file called init.properties:

```
username=fisk
password=frosk
```

and a Java class with some properties:

```
class Connection {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I want to do this:

```
Connection c = MagicConfigurator.configure("init.properties", new Connection())
```

and have MagicConfigurator apply all the values from the properties file to the Connection instance.

Is there a library with a class like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty simple using [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/). The library even takes care of type conversions. Additionally, you may even set properties of nested objects and arrays.

```
public static void setProperties(Object bean, Properties properties) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
  for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> e : properties.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getKey() instanceof String) {
      BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, (String) e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

As an example, you could use a properties file like this one:

```
username=john
keys[0]=47
keys[1]=11
person.name=John
person.age=42
```

Keys and age are converted to numbers on the fly. The keys array must be created in advance though, same for Person.

Answer (score 1):

A library? It's just a few lines of code:

For each and every key:

1. Convert the key name into a setter method name (basic string operations)
2. Get the Method object from the the configuration class object (reflection API)
3. Invoke the configuration object's setter with the value as an argument (invocation API)

You could even add this to the configuration class and implement a constructor that reads a Properties object.

Comment: Sure, I can write it myself, but if there's already a standard solution I can reuse I won't bother.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly straightforward to do this the with introspection class BeanInfo.

e.g. at the heart of it would be something like this.

```
public void readProperties(Object o, Properties p) throws IntrospectionException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
{
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(o.getClass());
    for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors())
    {
        String value = p.getProperty(propertyDescriptor.getName());
        if ( value != null && propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod() != null )
        {
            propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod().invoke(o, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Preferences](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for this

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/), and see if it there exists an equivalent of [commons digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) making use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer: look for the [Properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) for the first part. There are method to load/store.

I don't remember exactly, but I read some discussion about this class somewhere saying it had a funny design. It especially inherits `Hashtable`, but does not strictly behave like a `Hashtable`. I don't remember the arguments, but I think it was about the fact that the is-a relationship is not really correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would say just do it yourself (as Andreas_D has suggested), it really is simple, the only 'hard' part is doing the type conversion.

But if you really want to do this using a library, you might find the powerful expression syntax in OGNL helpful.

http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl/

1. Load the properties file into a Properties Object
2. Create an instance of the object you're interested in.
3. Put this item onto the OGNL stack.
4. For each property, use the OGNL stack to set the value. (something like `stack.setValue( "property", value );` )

The added bonus is that you can access properties of component objects too using the full OGNL syntax. You can do something like `stack.setValue( "property.name", value );` where there is a `getProperty()` that returns and object with a `get/setName()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use xml instead of properties, you could use JaxB.