# Populate default values through reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection, mocking, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a complex object hierarchy that has a couple of extends.

I am looking for a library that can reflectively insert default values on all fields.

For instance:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Color color;
    List<Clothes> clothes;
}

class Child extends Person {
    Sibling sibling;
}

class Foo {
   Person person;
   Child child;
}
```

I would like a library that take an object as parameter, in this case the `Foo` class, and then reflectively insert default values (even better if I can define default values) on all fields. Also all maps,list,sets etc should get a new

I have looked at [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils), but to my knowledge, it doesn't support exactly what I am looking for.

NB: These are just examples, and my objects are much more complex and big. They have many objects, and each object has many objects and so on. Both with maps, lists etc.

Is it maybe better to combine some libraries like BeanUtils and Google Guava and make it my own?

Comment: How do you provide said default values?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought of maybe using Guava's Defaults class which return default values based on primitive type

Comment: How is your "which values should I put in where?" data structure represented?

Comment: Your question was answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880284/which-java-library-lets-me-initialize-an-objects-properties-from-a-properties-fi

Comment: @Kris: This is close, but I dont want to use a property file, because the domain object might change, and I don't want to manually set values. I just want default values

Comment: But defaults have to come from somewhere, you can use other source than the properties file, otherwise just initialize all member variables in constructor with defaults and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

It should be fairly simple to do in one method provided you have the structure already built (in when case setting them as you build is a more logical approach)

If you know the default values in advance, why not just set them in the class? (i.e. default, default values ;)

Is there much value in setting a default name for a person (other than null)  Can you give an example of where you would want to specify the default value dynamically?

Comment: I cant change the class. Its serialized, and I don't want to change it. I basically want to create a mock object with default values that I can test with. Maybe there are some mocking frameworks there?

Comment: You can create a mock object by creating an object and giving it values.  You only need to use a framework when you want to mock functionality, i.e. methods.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just try to use normal java constructors, and/or getters and setters etc.  However from the question I'm guessing you want something that can work without knowing the exact structure of your classes.

So if you really have to do this, you could probably do something along the lines of the following:

```
public void setFields(Object myObject) {
    Class<?> clazz = myObject.getClass();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        String name = field.getName();
        if(name.equals("person")) {
            field.set(myObject, new Person());
        } else if (name.equals("color")) {
             // etc...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is too much work. I want a more dynamic way of doing it.